# Cassandra connections keep increasing

Tags: cassandra, nosql

My application's connection with cassandra keep increasing, MaxConnectionsPerHost doesn't work. i'm windering why?

Here's my configration.

```
    Builder builder = Cluster.builder();
    builder.withRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.INSTANCE);
    // JMX 配置
    builder.withoutJMXReporting().withoutMetrics();
    //DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy dCAwareRoundRobinPolicy = new   DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy("DC1", 2);
    builder.withLoadBalancingPolicy(new RoundRobinPolicy());

    // 添加节点
    for (String host : this.agentHosts) {
        builder.addContactPoints(host);
    }

    builder.withPort(this.port);

    cluster = builder.build();

    PoolingOptions poolingOptions =  cluster.getConfiguration().getPoolingOptions();

    // 连接池配置
    poolingOptions.setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 20).setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, 2).setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, 20).setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, 2);

    // socket 链接配置
    SocketOptions socketOptions = cluster.getConfiguration().getSocketOptions();
    socketOptions.setKeepAlive(true).setReceiveBufferSize(1024 * 1024).setSendBufferSize(1024 * 1024).setConnectTimeoutMillis(5 * 1000).setReadTimeoutMillis(1000);
    //builder.withSocketOptions(socketOptions);

    // Query 配置
    QueryOptions queryOptions = cluster.getConfiguration().getQueryOptions();
    queryOptions.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.ONE);
    //builder.withQueryOptions(queryOptions);

    logger.info("Connected to cluster: {}\n", cluster.getMetadata().getClusterName());
    cassandraSession = cluster.connect(KEY_SPACE);
```

As you can see, I set the MaxConnectionsPerHost is 20, but the connection's with cassandra hosts some usually exceeds 20. 
The details is my application is deployed on 192.168.1.23, and the cassandra hosts is 192.168.1.12~192.168.1.19, hosts 192.168.1.12~192.168.1.16 is a data center and 192.168.1.17~192.168.1.19 is another data center. The connections between 192.168.1.23 and cassandra hosts usually exceeds 20, like 100.

Comment: What version of the driver?  There are known connection leaks present in the java-driver that should have all been fixed by 2.0.9 and 2.1.5.

Comment: cassandra-driver-core-2.0.1.jar

Comment: That is an outdated version, so I think it would be worth upgrading to 2.0.10.  I'm relatively confident that will solve your problems.

Additionally, you should never configure SocketOptions.setReadTimeoutMillis() to a value less than read_request_timeout_in_ms as configured in your cassandra.yaml file on your cassandra node.   ReadTimeoutMillis is only used as a failsafe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my java-driver from cassandra-driver-core-2.0.1.jar to cassandra-driver-core-2.1.4.jar and the problem was solved.